# How to identify whether a variable is a class or an object

Tags: python

I am working at a bit lower level writing a small framework for creating test fixtures for my project in Python. In this I want to find out whether a particular variable is an instance of a certain class or a class itself and if it is a class, I want to know if it is a subclass of a certain class defined by my framework. How do I do it?

```
class MyBase(object):
    pass

class A(MyBase):
    a1 = 'Val1'
    a2 = 'Val2'

class B(MyBase):
    a1 = 'Val3'
    a2 = A
```

I want to find out if the properties a1 and a2 are instances of a class/type (a1 is a string type in B) or a class object itself (i.e a2 is A in B). Can you please help me how do I find this out?

Comment: Why can't you read the source?  What's wrong with your source?

Comment: What does that mean? You mean I should read the source code, parse it and find out? I want to find out programmatically and dynamically at run time. How can I achieve this by reading the source code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#module-inspect).

> The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods, functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects. For example, it can help you examine the contents of a class, retrieve the source code of a method, extract and format the argument list for a function, or get all the information you need to display a detailed traceback.

For example, the [`inspect.isclass()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) function returns true if the object is a class:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isclass(inspect)
False
>>> inspect.isclass(inspect.ArgInfo)
True
>>>
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know about this one, much better than the `isinstance` alternatives

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know about this too. Helps me a lot. I am using a combination of this and the solution given by inklesspen and abyx. Thanks everyone for the solution

Answer (score 4):

Use `isinstance` and `type`, `types.ClassType` (that latter is for old-style classes):

```
>>> isinstance(int, type)
True

>>> isinstance(1, type)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `type()` function. It will return the type of the object. You can get 'stock' types to match with from the [types](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) library. Old-style classes (that don't inherit from anything) have the type `types.ClassType`. New-style classes like in your example have the type `types.TypeType`. There are plenty of other useful types in this module for strings and such.

Calling `type()` on an instance of an old-style class returns `types.InstanceType`. Calling it on an instance of a new-style class returns the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use type()

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> print type(A)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> A = "abc"
>>> print type(A)
<type 'str'>
```